# Upgrade to Drupal 10.1.6, Theme Doesn't Load Outside Maintenance Mode

Tags: theming, upgrading

I'm working to upgrade a site from 9.5.11 to 10.1.6. I followed the instructions provided here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site

The upgrade went fine using composer, but when I visit the site after the upgrade I noticed that the site's theme isn't being loaded. The site is displayed as a long series of menus with content at the bottom of my browser window. I flushed all caches, still no luck. On a whim, I put the site back into maintenance mode, and suddenly everything looks fine again. The problem reappears if I bring the site out of maintenance mode.

I have full access to all menus while viewing the theme-less site, and I've tried switching themes, including trying to use the default Olivero theme, to see if that made a difference. It doesn't. Did I miss something with the upgrade? Can anyone help identify the problem?

Comment: What happens when you disable JavaScript and CSS aggregation?

Comment: Hmm, it works after disabling both JavaScript and CSS aggregation. Should those options not be used?

Comment: Yes they should be used. Back when Drupal 10.1 released it shipped with some changes to the front-end asset system—to aggregation specifically. This was a problem for some sites. What does the web browser console log? Look through the recent asset system issues: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=asset+library+system

Comment: Also read the release notes for recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Sure enough, the change to my nginx configuration was needed. the issue remained after that change though, and I saw multiple "too many redirects" errors in the browser console log. The fix described in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3368769 (comment #11) finally did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal 10.1.x introduced [CSS and JavaScript aggregation performance improvements](https://www.drupal.org/node/2888767) in that there is change to `.htaccess` file as well.

Sites using nginx/php-fpm may need to update their nginx.conf file to pass through the css/js path to Drupal.

Before

```
# Passes style generation to PHP.
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```

After

```
# Passes image style and asset generation to PHP.
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/(css|js|styles)/ {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```

Refer Change Record for more details.