# Drupal wouldn't acknowledge receiving updates, so I tried running the update in GitPod terminal and now Drupal is messed up!

Tags: composer

I setup a Drupal 10.0 test site (to do the LinkedIn Learning courses) on a windows machine using some combination of WSL, Composer, XAMPP. I would access it at https://imrodmartin-ddevgitpod-ytggsedst1i.ws-us106.gitpod.io/

It recommended updating to 10.1.6. I tried multiple times using "composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies" in a powershell window in the drupal folder with the json file. Terminal would appear to run the updates. But when reloading the drupal page, it insisted that I was still on 10.0. Tried running the command in multiple folders, cache clearing refresh. No dice.

So then I thought I was running the command in the wrong place and maybe it needed to be run on the terminal within the aforementioned gitpod. It scrolled through and performed the update. Now the drupal window is all wrong. No graphics, lots of plain text and scrolling.

Is there any way to just undo that update?? I have no idea how to get back to where I was and then properly perform the update. What am I doing wrong? Please halp. TIA!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! DA is a question-and-answer site where useful questions and answers are upvoted by site contributors. In this way it is different from an ordinary support forum. I recognize that you are having trouble with Drupal, unfortunately "what am I doing wrong?" is not answerable with facts due to there not being enough technical detail in the question as written. In order to provide a factual answer we will have to interview you, an this site is not set up for interviewing, and it does not encourage interviewing.

Comment: May be you need to update nginx conf as mentioned here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317493/upgrade-to-drupal-10-1-6-theme-doesnt-load-outside-maintenance-mode/317494#317494