# How can I modify the nginx configuration in the Docker image?

Tags: 10

I tried to use one of the two themes that came with Drupal - Olivero - and it is working in Maintenance mode, but once I switch maintenance mode off, I have a white page with a long list of menu item w/o any styling.

Initially, I installed drupal:10-fpm-alpine using Docker, which is now updated to drupal 10.2.4. It has nginx/1.22.1, PHP 8.2.12 and MySQL 8.0.35. When I saw a solution in this thread: [Upgrade to Drupal 10.1.6, Theme Doesn't Load Outside Maintenance Mode](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317493/upgrade-to-drupal-10-1-6-theme-doesnt-load-outside-maintenance-mode), I got excited. However, being a newbie, I'm not sure how to apply the suggestion in this thread, because I only have these two nginx.conf files:

/var/lib/docker/overlay2/464cd198c9f1ece0e669690a0a61d353e1d3f8b457489ab24eee2f12c637aff3/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae457ff4ced0f9e2e384a51fc1fc502f299652899cf0bd5321b7777f2e7568c5/diff/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

and they don't have the following part that is referred in the solution above:

## Passes style generation to PHP.

location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

or anything else PHP related. Could you give me advice?

Comment: Did you happen to see this, which was linked in the Drupal 10.1.0 release notes? https://www.drupal.org/node/2888767#nginx-php-fpm

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am not sure I can apply it, because I only have the following two nginx.conf files:

/var/lib/docker/overlay2/464cd198c9f1ece0e669690a0a61d353e1d3f8b457489ab24eee2f12c637aff3/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae457ff4ced0f9e2e384a51fc1fc502f299652899cf0bd5321b7777f2e7568c5/diff/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

and they don't have the "before" part that I could edit to look like the "after" part in the solution under that link.  Perhaps it is because I am using Docker and php-fpm is not set up the way it would be on a "normal" server?

Comment: If you are unable to edit Docker files, that isn't a Drupal question.

Comment: I see.  Could you recommend a forum where I could ask this question?

Comment: FWIW it looks like the Drupal Docker image is based right off https://hub.docker.com/_/php/.

Comment: Thank you for moving me in the right direction!  I will ask it at the Docker forum.

Answer (score 0):

In the Drupal [10.1.0 release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/10.1.0), there was an [update to the recommended nginx config](https://drupal.org/node/2888767#nginx-php-fpm).

It should now be:

```
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/(css|js|styles)/ {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```